# Mapping godaddy domain with AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, wordpress, godaddy

I have a word-press website running on EC2. I have a domain registered with godaddy. I used the elastic IP from AWS EC2 to set up A record.

The problem is, only the main page shows www.domainname.com, other pages ends up showing elastic IP.

Is there anything I am missing here ?

Comment: paste the record from godaddy DNS please

Comment: A (Host): Host @ Points To: (my elastic ip) TTL : 1 hr

Comment: I have edited the existing A record. Do I need to add new one or editing the existing one should do just fine ?

Comment: If you edited to fix something in the record itself, it will span and update within a half hour or so.

Comment: I had edited the A record to point to my elastic IP and it reflected after sometime. My issue is it works only on landing page of website and shows actual domain name in browser. For other pages of the website it shows elastic IP and not domain name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your WordPress settings at Settings -> General. Change those two URL fields to be the domain name, not the IP address.